# Mathematic function that takes any number above 90 and returns 90 minus the quantity above 90

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

For instance:

```
100 returns 10
101 returns 11
150 returns 60
but
87 returns 87
```

Is this possible exclusively with mathematics?

Comment: What is the function to be used for?

Answer (score 3):

Depends what you mean, I suppose. You can write a piecewise function that does this precisely.
$$
f(n)=\begin{cases} n-90&n>90\\n&n\leq 90\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

$x+ 90\big(\big(\frac{1}{2}\frac{|90-x|}{90-x}\big) - \frac{1}{2}\big)$

it's just doesnt defined for $x=90$

Comment: You can change the fraction to $\frac{|90.5 - x|}{90.5 - x}$.